# Is is possible to decouple event type name from the persisted event?

Tags: akka-persistence

I'd like to have some freedom in renaming of events or packages where they are placed. But currently this breaks persistence terribly.

Is it possible to annotate event with some string or even uuid which will be treated as event name by persistence layer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use a serializer with string manifest, see the akka docs:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/serialization.html#serializer-with-string-manifest

Or take a look at some example code here: 
https://github.com/benniekrijger/todo-service

The serializer from the example:
https://github.com/benniekrijger/todo-service/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/todos/protobuf/TodoSerializer.scala

And the required configuration:
https://github.com/benniekrijger/todo-service/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.conf#L13